# Mostrar datos de una tabla en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

quisiera listar los datos de mi tabla pero no lo consigo. No se si esta mal mi consulta, he mirado por todos los foros y no encuentro nada

Clase Lista

```
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView lv ;
ArrayList<String> lista;
ArrayAdapter adaptador;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    lista = db.llenar_lv();
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista);
    lv.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

}

clase DbHelper

```
    public void addUser(String usurarios, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_usurarios, usurarios);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);

    long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Usuario insertado" + id);
}





public boolean getUser(String usurarios, String pass){
    //HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "select * from  " + USER_TABLE + " where " +
            COLUMN_usurarios + " = " + "'"+usurarios+"'" + " and " + COLUMN_PASS + " = " + "'"+pass+"'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        return true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return false;
}

public String eliminar(String usuarios){
    String mensaje="";

    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

    int cantidad = db.delete(USER_TABLE ,COLUMN_usurarios+"=?",new String[]{usuarios});

    if(cantidad!=0){
        mensaje="eliminado correctamente";
    }else{
        mensaje="No existe";
    }
    db.close();
    return mensaje;
}
public ArrayList llenar_lv(){
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT * FROM users";
    Cursor registros = db.rawQuery(q,null);
    if(registros.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            lista.add(registros.getString(0));
        }while(registros.moveToNext());
    }
    return lista;

}
```

}

Y este es el layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.techobbyist.signuplogin.LoginActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        ></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat

> ```
> 11-25 00:48:34.475 13742-13742/com.techobbyist.signuplogin W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextBeforeCursor on inactive
> ```
>
> InputConnection 11-25 00:48:34.480
>   13742-13742/com.techobbyist.signuplogin W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection 11-25 00:48:34.585
>   13742-13742/com.techobbyist.signuplogin W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection 11-25 00:48:34.675
>   13742-13742/com.techobbyist.signuplogin W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection 11-25 00:48:34.680
>   13742-13742/com.techobbyist.signuplogin W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection 11-25 00:48:34.680
>   13742-13742/com.techobbyist.signuplogin W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

Comment: Que te muestra tu logcat ?

Comment: Nada, cuando le doy al boton de listar, no me hace nada @AshleyG.

Comment: @zzxbx definitivamente tienes que mirar en el LogCat, si se cierra la aplicación algo debe mostrarse, ¿Lo sabes usar sin problema el LogCat?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69240/discussion-on-question-by-zzxbx-mostrar-datos-de-una-tabla-en-android-studio).